# Can't draw RECT on pygame ffs

Tags: pygame

this is the code: [image: the code]

this is the pygame output[image: the output of the code]
I have not been able to create a very simple shape/sprite.

Comment: Could you place here you code instead of an image?

Comment: Please provide your code as a code snippet instead of an image. Also, it seems to be a simple indentation error - just indenting the last 2 lines by 1 level (to the same as the `while` loop probably would fix your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code you are using to draw the red rectangle is after the while loop. Your program is stalling in the while loop and never reaches the drawing line.

Try moving:

```
pygame.draw.rect(stage, red, (x,y,width,height))
pygame.display.update()
```

to before the `while running:` statement

or if you want it to draw the rectangle every *tick* include that statement directly under the `while running:` statement

Answer (score 0):

Indent the lines:

```
pygame.draw.rect(stage, red, (x,y,width,height))
pygame.display.update()
```

four spaces to the right. This will put them inside the for loop, and so will redraw the rectangle on every iteration of the loop.